# Unhelpful warnings() and problems() when importing ~3400 CSV files in R

Tags: r, warnings

I am reading in all the CSV files in a directory using read_csv in a loop and rbinding each file to a main dataframe, and after doing that, I see that there are 13 warnings.

Running warnings() like it says to yeild this, with the same warning message 13 times.

```
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: One or more parsing issues, call `problems()` on your data frame for details, e.g.:
  dat <- vroom(...)
  problems(dat)
2: One or more parsing issues, call `problems()` on your data frame for details, e.g.:
  dat <- vroom(...)
  problems(dat)
3: One or more parsing issues, call `problems()` on your data frame for details, e.g.:
  dat <- vroom(...)
  problems(dat)
```

Then I run problems() and get this (which I don't know what to make of)

```
> problems(genomic_db)
# A tibble: 0 × 5
# … with 5 variables: row <int>, col <int>, expected <chr>, actual <chr>, file <chr>
# ℹ Use `colnames()` to see all variable names
```

Then running colnames gives me all the expected dataframe column names. I'm at a loss at how to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: When you load all files in a loop, are you doing anything to the frame after the `read_*` function call? I would not be surprised if the attributes that `vroom` attaches to the frame are lost on any subsequent processing.

Comment: Already tried the original `read.csv()`?

Comment: Are you explicitly defining a delimiter in `vroom()`? Are you 100% confident your data are "clean"? It could be that some columns are being converted to the wrong type because of an erroneous character. There might also be a stray delimiter and the columns are being "bumped" along. One way to check would be to loop over your files and `print(str(yourfile))` without rbinding them. Then you'll at least see if all your files are being interpreted the same way.